Flutter build failing due to Kotlin version mismatch in Gradle
Flutter build fails after updating to new Kotlin version
I'm working on a Flutter project, and after updating some dependencies, I encountered a build error. I'm using the latest version of Kotlin, and when I run flutter build apk, it fails with the following errors:
e: C:/Users/Moham/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/1a36c150372f3edd1303b1fe7aa45a27/transformed/fragment-1.7.1-api.jar!/META-INF/fragment_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          251.8s

┌─ Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                                 │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update the  │
│ version number of the plugin with id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" in the plugins block of            │
│ C:\flutter_app\lklk-live\android\settings.gradle.                                                      │
│                                                                                                        │
│ Alternatively (if your project was created before Flutter 3.19), update                                │
│ C:\flutter_app\lklk-live\android\build.gradle                                                          │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                                │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘



It seems to suggest that the Kotlin versions are incompatible. Here’s the setup in my build.gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


settings.gradle:
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.20" apply false
}

include ":app"


It seems I need to update the Kotlin Gradle plugin, but I’m unsure how to properly resolve this issue. I also see a suggestion to update the plugin in C:\flutter_app\lklk-live\android\build.gradle, but I’ve already set the kotlin_version to the latest version (2.0.20).
Has anyone experienced this issue? How can I resolve this Kotlin version incompatibility?
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2486], locale en-US)

Hey, check this gradle, agp, kotlin version compability. Gradle Compability Matrix. That 3 part need to synchronize the version to get it work.

Add this code in your android/build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '2.0.20' //Your preferred Kotlin Version
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}


If you can't find buildscript in android/build.gradle like Nipul Rathod Answer, you probably already have a newer version flutter project that have a different flutter gradle plugin structure (read this migration guide for older project). In the newest flutter gradle plugin structure:
Find this code in your android/settings.gradle:
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.5.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.20" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.10" apply false
}

To edit your kotlin version change the "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version.

I had a similar error where the Kotlin version was not compatible the gradle versions, this is how I fixed it:
This is my project/build.gradle file:
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '2.0.20' //Your preferred Kotlin Version
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
    
    rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
    subprojects {
        project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    }
    subprojects {
        project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
    }
    
    tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }

This is my settings.gradle file:
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.5.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.20" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.10" apply false
}

include ":app"

My app/build.gradle file:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.flutte_app"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.flutte_app"
        minSdk = flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutter.versionCode
        versionName = flutter.versionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

And then in the AndroidManifest.xml (location: /android/app/src/main) file I removed the " package="com.example.yourapp" " at the very top.

should mention what fixed issue instead of just suggesting others to copy and paste the code.

Yeah see, but that's the issue the code flutter gave me is the way beginning was so outdated, I had to rewrite it to what it is now, so I don't know what specifically helped because I had to change everything.
